# Chrome won't work after Windows 10 update

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, windows-update

After a forced update on Windows 10 (to Version 10.0.17134.376) I can't access any site with Google Chrome.

Every time I try to visit a site it times out (ERR_TIMED_OUT).

Microsoft Edge (which suddenly appeared among my desktop icons) appears to work fine.

I've tried

- Restarting the computer
- Reinstalling Google Chrome
- Running the "compatibility problems" dialog on the Chrome application

Nothing has worked.

Any ideas to what I can do?

Comment: When you say Edge was suddenly installed does that mean you removed it?  What build were you running before you installed `KB4462933`, I suspect what you were actually using 1709 and due to your Windows Update settings upgraded to 1803.  Have you tried to delete your Chrome user profile?  Please provide all relevant information in an update to your question instead of a comment.  Be sure to include the Chrome build you are using.

Comment: If you syncronized your user/got backup of your favorites passwords etc.  I should navigate to  "%LOCALAPPDATA%\  , delete the folder called 'Google' . then start chrome again. this is a simple way to save time. makes things less complicated =)

Comment: Tracked by Chromium project here: https://crbug.com/838707#c205

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### The problem

The problem has been discussed on Google Chrome's help forum:

> The problem started with the April 2018 Win10 1803 Feature Update and can also happen with fresh Windows installs that use 1803. It is an (unknown) artifact of how Windows is installed or updated. The 1803 update can cause a core Windows identity service (CryptSvc) to loop endlessly and stall connections. --  https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/s5S1uPI0kMc

#### Are you affected?

Try the following steps to see if you are affected by this problem:

1. Open Task Manager
2. Go to services
3. Find the CryptSvc service
4. Right click and restart the service

Can you browse sites with Google Chrome now? If so, you are affected and this is only a temporary fix.

#### Permanent solution

There are a lot of suggestions for solutions around (just google `chrome CryptSvc fix`)

[The simplest fix](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-networking/april-2018-update-broke-chrome-browser/f0204aa2-4c93-42b7-a6dc-c9ee6b42da0c) (that worked for me) came from the Microsoft Forum.

(*I have slightly altered the solution for easier understanding.*)

1. Run `regedit`
2. Go to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\Root`
3. Right click "ProtectedRoots" and click "Permissions"
4. Select your user account and tick "Allow Full Control"
5. Take a backup of `Root` by right clicking and click export, and save it somewhere
6. Open Task Mananger and stop the "Cryptographic Service"
7. Delete the `Software\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\Root` registry entry
8. Restart Windows

Comment: Thank you for posting this! Solved my issue. I tried like 10 other things before this and they didn't work, so very glad you posted this : )

Comment: Glad I could help @AdmiralAdama :)

Comment: This solved my problem, with one caveat: I had to take ownership of one of the keys involved in the delete (https://superuser.com/a/909016). The delete of one of `Root`'s children failed until I took ownership of that child key.

Answer (score 1):

I have fix it with our environment, we are using Windows 10 Eng 64bit Enterprise 1803 or 1809 clients and Windows 2016 server AD with mandatory login profile, Chrome is V70 64bit default profile is roaming also and getting this problem of Chrome not going on the internet and it take a long time to show web pages. What I did do was change the Crypto services logon from Network services to local system account and allow services to interact with desktop land added domain users to the Cryto services to start/stop.

It seems to work OK now, let me know if it works for you.  I did it with GPO.

Answer (score -2):

All I had to do was go to Program Files(x86) --> Google --> Chrome --> Application

Then rename chrome.exe name to chrome..exe  (add an extra period)

This solved my issue and I was able to browse again!!