# Trouble with registry key updating/uninstalling iTunes

Tags: permissions, windows-registry, itunes, file-association, windows-installer

I am trying to update iTunes and the updater fails. So I then decided  to manually download the installer, however it then throws an error saying it could not open the registry key `HKLM\Software\Classes\.m4b`. So I then went into Apps and Features and attempted to uninstall the existing version, however it throws the same error message. Finding it odd, I went into Registry Editor and tried to navigate to the said key, which then gave the following error message: `.m4b cannot be opened. An error is preventing this key from being opened. Details: Access is denied.` And neither can I change the permissions of the registry key or delete it, despite running Registry Editor as Administrator.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Run `regedit` as an Administrator then provide the permissions on the key in question, as a screenshot, and provide this screenshot by editing your quesiton

Comment: Added, See changes.

Comment: Are you able to view any other key located under HKLM\Software\Classes\`?  If you can't there is no easy solution to that problem

Comment: Mostly, but scrolling up with the arrow keys, `.ac3` and `.IVF` also throw up the same error.

Comment: [Start your PC in safe mode](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/start-your-pc-in-safe-mode-in-windows-92c27cff-db89-8644-1ce4-b3e5e56fe234) and try deleting that key?

Comment: Same error message....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am finally able to solve it! Using the method with `PSTools` as described [here](https://superuser.com/a/1316937/238932) I was able to run Registry Editor as the `SYSTEM` account, assigning Full Control  permissions to Everyone on the problematic key, and then delete it, now the installer proceeds with no issue.

Comment: You will want to correct the permissions on all the keys.  Any application that uses .ac3 and .IVF won't be able to access the applicable registry keys